# Changing default editor for markdown bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, editors, markdown

I am pretty new to bash/zsh on Mac OX. I am trying to change my `.bash_profile` so that that all markdowns are opened with sublime when I enter `open [filename].md` in terminal. I have created  synthetic link to the binary and opening with `subl [filname].md` works just great but when I try to add `export EDITOR=subl` it does not work so I am assuming I am doing something wrong here. I do not have a `.bashrc`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install "sublime text" on your Mac?  Did you download the Mac version?

Since "open" on the Mac is unique to the Mac, this is more of a Mac "Finder" question ...

In Finder, single click on one of the .md files and issue "Get Info".  Within that window, Select "sublime text" to "open with" then click on "Change all".

Now when you issue `open filename.md` it should open with sublime text.

Comment: I was hoping to do this in command line. when I do `open filename.md` in terminal it does not work but `subl filename.md` works. I tried your method above but it does not change things :-(

Comment: Actually, now it works! :-) Any suggestions on how to make sublime by default editor though? Why does the export not work?

Comment: Show the full command you used to create the symbolic link to subl. You want "EDITOR" to reflect the fully qualified path name to subl. Apple changed it's default shell to zsh .. Are you sure that bash is your default shell? Please accept the answer to your original answer. Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as "accepted", in order to indicate that the answer solved your problem. Accepting an answer is beneficial as it rewards posters for correctly answering your question and informs others that your issue is resolved.